# How to forecast actual future values using XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost, forecasting

So I have a solar Irradiation dataset having around 61000+ rows & 2 columns. I have made the model using XGBoost to predict the future values.

I have splitted the data in 2 parts train and test and trained the model accordingly. Furthermore, I have made the predictions on the test data set. Everything is going fine. But now I want to predict the actual forecast How can I do that ??

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from xgboost import plot_importance
from sklearn import metrics

# Dataset
df=pd.read_csv('Readings_last_7yr.csv')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

## Copied the dataset

df2 = df.copy()
del df2['Date']

## Test Train Split

from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
# series = read_csv('sunspots.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
X = df2
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.75)
train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:len(X)]
print('Observations: %d' % (len(X)))
print('Training Observations: %d' % (len(train)))
print('Testing Observations: %d' % (len(test)))
pyplot.plot(train)
pyplot.plot(test)
pyplot.show()


## Creating Features
def create_features(df, target_variable):
    
    df['date'] = df.index
    df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour
    df['dayofweek'] = df['date'].dt.dayofweek
    df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.quarter
    df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
    df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
    df['dayofyear'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear
    df['dayofmonth'] = df['date'].dt.day
    df['weekofyear'] = df['date'].dt.weekofyear
    
    X = df[['hour','dayofweek','quarter','month','year',
           'dayofyear','dayofmonth','weekofyear']]
    if target_variable:
        y = df[target_variable]
        return X, y
    return X

## METRICS

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

def timeseries_evaluation_metrics_func(y_true, y_pred):
    print(f'MSE is : {metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)}')
    print(f'MAE is : {metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)}')
    print(f'RMSE is : {np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))}')
    print(f'MAPE is : {mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)}')
    print(f'R2 is : {metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)}',end='\n\n')

train_copy = train.copy()
test_copy = test.copy()

trainX, trainY = create_features(train_copy, target_variable='Irr')
testX, testY = create_features(test_copy, target_variable='Irr')

xgb = XGBRegressor(objective= 'reg:linear', n_estimators=1000)
xgb

xgb.fit(trainX, trainY,
        eval_set=[(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)],
        early_stopping_rounds=50,
        verbose=False)


# Predictions 
predicted_results = xgb.predict(testX)

# Metrics
timeseries_evaluation_metrics_func(testY, predicted_results)

# Plotting graph for test and Predicted
plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
plt.plot(list(testY))
plt.plot(list(predicted_results))
plt.title("Actual vs Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Irr")
plt.legend(('Actual','predicted'))
plt.show()

# Making graph of predicted on the whole dataframe
test['Prediction'] = predicted_results
Irr_all = pd.concat([test, train], sort=False)
Irr_all = Irr_all.rename(columns={'Irradiation':'Original_Value'})

Overview_Complete_Data_And_Prediction = Irr_all[['Irr','Prediction']].plot(figsize=(12, 5))
```

I am getting the results as:
[image]

[image]

So now I want to predict future values from the year 2021 till 2023.

## FUTURE PREDICTION

```
dti = pd.date_range("2021-01-01 00:30:00", periods=20000, freq="H")
df_future_dates = pd.DataFrame(dti, columns = ['Date'])
df_future_dates['Irr'] = np.nan
df_future_dates.index = pd.to_datetime(df_future_dates['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_future_dates_copy = df_future_dates.copy()
testX_future, testY_future = create_features(df_future_dates, target_variable='Irr')

xgb = XGBRegressor(objective= 'reg:linear', n_estimators=1000)
xgb

## Now here I have used train and test from above
xgb.fit(trainX, trainY,
        eval_set=[(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)],
        early_stopping_rounds=50,
        verbose=False) 

predicted_results_future = xgb.predict(testX_future)

# Graph 
plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
plt.plot(list(predicted_results_future))
plt.title("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Irr")
plt.legend(('predicted'))
plt.show()

df_future_dates_copy['Prediction'] = predicted_results_future
Irr_all_future = pd.concat([df2, df_future_dates_copy], sort=False)

# Future Graph 
Overview_Complete_Data_And_Prediction_future = Irr_all_future[['Irr','Prediction']].plot(figsize=(15, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: I think `xgb.predict(last_known_value_of_the_data)` is the forecast you're looking for

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks but how to add the end date like when to stop. Also, should I take the actual value of the data or the predicted data?

Comment: I think you should take the latest (from 2021) value of `testX`. But then you won't have any X data from the future, right? So you'll probably have to build another model to forecast X values and fees them to your original `xgb` model

Comment: @ForceBru Okay, so  I would take for example last 1000 values from the actual dataset where I have X and y. Now I will use the same model which I have used previously right? But how would I implement it?

Comment: @ForceBru  Hey man !! thanks I think I solved it correctly. Could you please check it ? I have updated the code. Please tell me any suggestions if needed. or if there is data leakage or any problem. Also why is the graph is kind of repeating from 2021 to 2022 and 2022 - 2023. Is that okay ??

Comment: you could try asking this on Cross Validated, which is a site specifically for data science and machine learning. You could probably show your results, describe your approach and ask whether this makes sense